# I have a problem with printing from a windows service

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, windows-services

I have created a windows service that prints pdf by reading from a collector (database table) but sometimes it happens that the service does not recognize the printing preferences set in the administrator user configuration.

When I developed the service, to avoid this problem, I changed the connection to the service by setting the administrator credentials to force the use of print preferences but now it no longer works correctly.

I read that when the administrator user is logged out something like this could happen and use the default print settings. How can I avoid this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Create a local windows user with admin (full) permissions and set password - never change. Then, in your service set "Run As" this user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  to solve the problem i used admin user directly in the windows service connection.  is not sufficient?

Comment: depends. our domains rip out admin users. Also, if password settings require change, may be not sufficient